# Data truncation: Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

Tags: java, spring, jpa, point, hibernate-spatial

hi i'm trying to insert and read **geo data(POINT)** to **mySQL DB.**

I am using **JPA**.

I got latitude and longitude from the frontend and I made a String like POINT(10 20) as wkt.

then by using WKTReader, I made a Point Object, made an entity , and call the jpa save method.

but I got `Data truncation: Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field` error.

what's wrong with my code?

by the way i used

`org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;`

+) when I tried to insert point as WKT(Stirng), it works. (and it is stored with BLOB in DB)
should I have to do like this????

### Service

```java
  @Transactional
    public void addClub (AddClubRequest clubRequest) throws ParseException {
        Member master = memberRepository.getReferenceById(clubRequest.getUserId());
  
        Point point = makePoint(clubRequest.getLatitude(), clubRequest.getLongitude());
    
        Club club = clubRequest.toClub(master, point);

        clubRepository.save(club);

    }

public Point makePoint (Float latitude, Float longitude) throws ParseException {
         String wkt = String.format("POINT(%s %s)", latitude, longitude);
         return (Point)new WKTReader().read(wkt);
    }
```

### Entity

```java
 @Column(name = "club_point", columnDefinition = "POINT")
    private Point clubPoint;
```

### yml

```yaml
spring  
 jpa :
    properties:
      hibernate:
        database-platform: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL8SpatialDialect
```

### build.gradle

```
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.6.3.Final'
    implementation group: 'org.locationtech.jts', name: 'jts-core', version: '1.16.1'
    implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-spatial', version: '5.6.15.Final'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yhe Objective here is to be able to save before encountering *"Data Truncation"*.

Your error seems to indicate that the data being sent isn't right.
I think we can try a different method to save the data using the MySQL function:

```
ST_PointFromText
```

In order to save the data directly.

That's how i would modify your code, starting by makePoint:

```
public String makePoint(Float latitude, Float longitude) {
    return String.format("POINT(%s %s)", latitude, longitude);
}
```

Now in your addClub:
`clubRepository.save(club);`
I'll modify it to:

```
clubRepository.saveWithPoint(club, makePoint(clubRequest.getLatitude(), clubRequest.getLongitude()));
```

And we create a new Method:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO club (club_name, club_point) VALUES (:clubName, ST_PointFromText(:point))", nativeQuery = true)
void saveWithPoint(@Param("clubName") String clubName, @Param("point") String point);
```

Don't forget to import all the stuff that you need.